# How to get field from Object class?

Tags: java

I have a object like below:

```java
public void getField(List<?> list) {
            int lastIndex = list.size()-1;
            Object ob = list.get(lastIndex);
}
```

How can I return a specific field from this `ob` like e.q. `status`?

Comment: Normally you use a cast to coerce the object to a type you know the fields of.

Comment: I have a generic function, i edit right now

Comment: @markspace can you show an example? my `status` is of type `BigInteger`

Comment: Can you show the code and the class types that you add to this list?  Where and what code calls this method?

Comment: class types is a simple dto from db

Comment: Please *show your code*.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Possible is the solution for your case:

```
public <T> T getField(List<T> list) {
    int lastIndex = list.size()-1;
    T ob = list.get(lastIndex);
    return ob;
}
```